# Array destructuring producing weird results

Tags: javascript, rust, google-chrome-headless

I am using playwrite-rust crate and executing some Js script into chrome. But I am running into something very weird not sure its about JS, browser, or the crate I am using. Anyhow I will share the problem.

Suppose this is the code I am executing through playwright-rust.

```
async function search(...args) {
    const [session_id, url] = args;
    console.log(args);
    console.log(args.length);
    console.log(url);
}
```

How its being called in Rust code:

```
let args = vec![session_id.clone(), build_url];
let json_result = tab
    .evaluate::<Vec<String>, serde_json::Value>(SEARCH, args)
    .await?;
```

I am expecting to have `url` and `session_id` respective value by array destructuring but that's not the case. Have a look here what I get in the browser:

[image]

args.length produces 1 and url is undefined. What is wrong here?

Comment: "destructuring", not "destruction".

Comment: You don't show how you call that function.

Comment: actually its being called internally via the library.

Comment: @foragerDev then do you follow the library's API? From where I stand, this is an error type 18.

Comment: @YanickRochon I am following that, I added a rust code please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array that contains another array. You should use

```
function search(...args) {
    const [[session_id, url]] = args;
}
```

or

```
function search(...args) {
    const [session_id, url] = args[0];
}
```

or

```
function search(arg) {
    const [session_id, url] = arg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my night.

Answer (score 1):

If Rust calls it like how you mentioned, that is

```
let args = vec![session_id.clone(), build_url];
let json_result = tab
    .evaluate::<Vec<String>, serde_json::Value>(SEARCH, args)
    .await?;
```

Then `args` is an array, therefore your `search` function should not have this signature :

```
type search(...args:string):any
```

but should have this signature :

```
type search(args:string[]):any
```

In other words, instead of this function :

```
function search(...args) {
    // args[0] = [session_id.clone(), build_url];
}
```

you should have this function :

```
function search([ session_id, build_url ]) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: seemingly, but as I wanted to pass multiple parameters so only way seems to be passing them through vector. But the confusing part is, I was using rust-headless-chrome, where it was working, my array was not wrapped inside another array. And I did not find anything in the documentation. Well issue resolved.

Comment: At least you understand that your Rust code calls a function with a single param. Your spread operator would have worked if the Rust code had been `..evaluate::<Vec<String>, serde_json::Value>(SEARCH, session_id.clone(), build_url)`. If you can understand that, then you won't repeat the same mistake.

Comment: But In rust you can't do that. You have to strictly follow the function signature, to the best of my knowledge [see here](https://docs.rs/playwright/0.0.20/playwright/api/page/struct.Page.html#method.evaluate). Yeah at least I understand now.

Comment: So, you are limited to a single argument in the function call, therefore you can't use a spread operator when using `.evaluate`. This is what the doc says :)